# How to make JSF 2.2.6 and RichFaces 4.5.0 work on JBoss 4.2.2.GA?

Tags: java, jsf, jboss, richfaces

I have an application running Mojarra 2.2.6 and Richfaces 4.5.0 it worked fine on Tomcat 7.0 but we need it to run on 4.2.2.GA for a client. The application used to run on the server without problems using JSF 2.2.4 and RF 4.1, now nothing seems to work on my local machine.

this is the error I get

```
11:10:15,719 ERROR [STDERR] sept. 09, 2015 11:10:15 AM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFOS: Initialisation de Mojarra 2.2.6 ( 20140304-1537 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.6@12949) pour le contexte «/EPS_2»
11:10:21,991 ERROR [STDERR] sept. 09, 2015 11:10:21 AM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory getProviderInstance
GRAVE: JSF1029 : The specified InjectionProvider implementation «org.jboss.web.jsf.integration.injection.JBossInjectionProvider»  does not implement the InjectionProvider interface.
11:10:22,385 ERROR [STDERR] sept. 09, 2015 11:10:22 AM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
INFOS: JSF1048 : PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations present. ManagedBeans methods marked with these annotations will have said annotations processed.
```

this is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>EPS</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- BEGIN PARAM FOR JBOSS DEPLOYMENT-->
<listener> 
        <listener-class>org.jboss.web.jsf.integration.config.JBossJSFConfigureListener</listener-class> 
    </listener>

    <context-param> 
        <param-name>org.jboss.jbossfaces.WAR_BUNDLES_JSF_IMPL</param-name> 
        <param-value>true</param-value> 
    </context-param>
<!-- <context-param> 
            <param-name>com.sun.faces.injectionProvider</param-name> 
            <param-value>org.jboss.web.jsf.integration.injection.JBossInjectionProvider</param-value> 
    </context-param>
 -->     
    <!-- JSF 2: use pages named .xhtml instead of .jsp. 
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    -->
    <!-- END   PARAM FOR JBOSS DEPLOYMENT-->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml,/WEB-INF/faces-managed-bean-param.xml,/WEB-INF/faces-navigation.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
        <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.skin</param-name>
    <param-value>blueSky</param-value>
</context-param>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>5</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Anything would help. Thank you :)

Comment: I changed it to english thank you, I was in a hurry :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had made a change in my faces-config.xml and it worked with JSF 2.2.4
I had version 2.1 updated to 2.2

**OLD :**

```
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">
```

**NEW :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">
```